Identifying House of Cards minor character
I was watching the latest season of House of Cards, and the actor that plays Jackie Sharp's new fiancée - the cardiologist - seems familiar to me, but I can't remember his name. He appeared in at least episodes 5 and 11 of the third season.
I have tried going through the cast lists on IMDb, but I can't find him. Here's an image:


I haven't watched this much of the series but Sharp isn't even in either of those two episodes. Are you sure about their connection? Is he just an extra (does he ever speak on camera)?

This has been driving me crazy as well but I think I found him! It might be Shawn Doyle http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0236495/?ref_=tt_cl_t3


Indeed he is credited as Dr. Alan Cooke, Cardiovascular surgeon (not cardiologist).
